# Filtering Apache mailing list emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail-filters

I've just subscribed to an [Apache mailing list](http://commons.apache.org/digester/mail-lists.html) and would like to filter out the incoming emails.

How do I create a filter to only receive the answers to my messages and not all posts from other users?

If this is not possible, how can I just receive the mails with **[digester]** as the subject line prefix?

Comment: What's your email of use here? Gmail? Yahoo!?

Comment: @Eight Days of Malaise gmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gmail create a filter:
 1. In *"Create Filter"* write into *Subject*: `-[digester]` and into *"Has the words"* write `list:user@commons.apache.org` (depending to which list you are subscribed to)
 2. In the next step select *"Delete it"*
This will delete  all mails received from the mailing list that do not contain [digester] in the subject the moment they arrive into your inbox.

UPDATE: I couldn't find a way to filter by `In-Reply-To` or `References` email header used by the mailing list to create threads but you could try something like this: 
`list:user@commons.apache.org (subject:(-[digester]) OR -your_email@gmail.com)`
This will keep also mails that contain your email address somewhere and so are likely to be replies to you.

Comment: ok and what about receiving only my answers.. is also possible ?